# How to write @Param and @Body in one DTO

Tags: nestjs, dto

I am using nestjs and I make an effort DTO's and I generate update-todo.dto.ts like this.

How can I use @Param and @Body together in one DTO?

```
@Param('id') id: string,
@Body('status') status: TodoStatus
```

So how to convert my code?

```
import { TodoStatus } from '../todo.model';
export class UpdateTodoDto {
  id: string;
  status: TodoStatus;
}
```

```
  @Patch('/:id/status')
  updateTodoStatus(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Body('status') status: TodoStatus
    // convert this line
  ): Todo {
    return this.todosService.updateTodoStatus(id, status);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You'd need, four components to work together.

1. A custom decorator to combine the `@Param()` and `@Body()` decorators
2. A DTO to hold the shape of the `@Param()` DTO
3. A DTO to hold the shape of the `@Body()` DTO
4. A DTO to combine the body and param DTOs

[This repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nestjs-optional-body) goes through an example with an optional body based on a query parameter.

## 1

```js
export const BodyAndParam = createParamDecorator((data: unknwon, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  return { body: req.body, params: req.params };
});
```

## 2

```js
export class ParamsDTO {

  @IsString()
  id: string;
}
```

## 3

```js
export class BodyDTO {
  @IsString()
  hello: string;
}
```

## 4

```js
export class MixedDTO {
  @Type(() => ParamsDTO)
  params: ParamsDTO;
  
  @Type(() => BodyDTO);
  body: BodyDTO;
}
```

## Use

```js
@Controller()
export class FooController {
  @Post()
  bar(@BodyAndParam() bodyAndParam: MixedDTO) {
    // do stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for answer. Now I know how to write :D